# Is there a way to archive all cards on a Trello list?

Tags: trello

I have a basic list setup on my board: **To do** / **Doing** / **Done**.

I've accumulated a crapload of cards in my **Done** column (go me!).  But I've gotten over myself and decided that **Done** should only contain stuff that I finished this week, making my weekly status report a cinch.

I see that I can archive an entire list, but is there a a way to archive all cards in a given list at once without archiving each one manually?

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts (specifically [Delete]) make this a little bit easier.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the tip @Daniel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By clicking the 3 dots at the top of the list you get a list of actions for the list where you can find **Archive All Cards in This List...** Maybe this option was not available by the time this question was asked, but today this is the way to do it.

[image: Trello archive list]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe one interim option might be to name the **Done** list as **Done week ending 04-11-2011**.
Then archive the whole list and create a new list for the following week.

Comment: This is just a suggestion of an alternative workflow and not a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

There does not currently exist a way to "bulk" archive a set of cards.

Comment: Will it be added to the dev board?